# Remove certain functionality from Rich Text Area field in Salesforce UI

Tags: inputtext, richtextarea, ui

I have added a

```
Rich Text Area
```

field to an object in Salesforce.

Is it possible to remove the Hyperlink and Attach Image buttons in the Salesforce UI?

I want my users to be able to use all of the other features available from a Rich Text Area, but not the Hyperlink or Attach Image functionality.

Is there a configuration option somewhere for this perhaps?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any configuration or setting for this is definitely available nowhere and using some sidebar component hack is not advisable as Salesforce will soon going to discontinue them.

So in short, I don't think anything like this is possible for now.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can hide the options. like

#cke_9,#cke_12,#cke_20,#cke_24{
    display:none;
}

[image]